# Duplicate Symbols for Architecture arm64

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, linker-errors

When I try running my Xcode Project it fails with an error stating that I have duplicate symbols. I looked online where the find these duplicates but have had no luck:

[image]

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: it means you've got too much of BFAppLinkReturnToRefererView

Comment: Also, you might want to clean up your project a bit rather than linking to frameworks sitting on your desktop. :)

Comment: In my case I have added extern NSString * const tColor; in .h file and NSString const *tColor = @"#000022"; in two different .m classes.

Comment: You may find what you look for here https://stackoverflow.com/a/46678210/988941

Answer (score 71, accepted):

From the errors, it would appear that the FacebookSDK.framework already includes the Bolts.framework classes. Try removing the additional Bolts.framework from the project.

Comment: how to? can you please guide me step by step

Comment: do you have any guide?

Answer (score 79):

For me it helped to switch the "No Common Blocks" compiler setting to NO:
It pretty much seems to make sense, the setting is explained here:
[What is GCC_NO_COMMON_BLOCKS used for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11233235/what-is-gcc-no-common-blocks-used-for)

Comment: You are the man! Just made a new xCode 7.3.1 project and the default setting is YES :(

Comment: This option was switched on for me by Xcode's "Update project to recommended settings" window.

Comment: You are the best

Comment: priceless tip, but doh didn't help in my case!  :O

Answer (score 54):

Using Xcode 8, "Update project to recommended settings" option turned ON 'No Common Blocks' for my project.

Turning it back to OFF fixed everything up.

Comment: Update project to recommended settings, how do i do that? i mean from which menu?

Comment: @SazzadHissainKhan It's in your build settings.

Answer (score 53):

I've messed up my pods while downgrading a pod and I've managed to resolve the issue with *duplicate symbols for architecture arm64* by removing the pods and installing them again with:

```
pod deintegrate
pod install
```

Comment: I was using the Google Places SDK, integrated through CocoPods - 3.9.0, and this answer fixed my issue.

Comment: Thanks, you saved me a lot of headache

Comment: Note you have to specify the exact project you want to deintegrate. I would recommend dragging the project from xcode itself as opposed to from your file explorer... Had over 450 of these arm64 errors...

Comment: Helps with switching the "No Common Blocks" compiler setting to NO

Comment: time-saving answer

Answer (score 28):

Another Solution is to:

> Select **Project** -> **Target** -> **Build phase** -> **Compile source** -> search
>   for the file which is mentioned in the 3rd last error line (In your
>   case **BFAppLinkReturnToRefererView.o**).

Then you will see either 1 or 2 files in search result.

**Remove** one of them and **compile again**. It should recompile now because there is only one file left and no more conflicts for build.

If that doesnt work the file probably has errors in it and you should remove all of them and then recompile. 
It should work again.

Comment: Extremely underrated answer, thanks for your help, Lukas! :)

Comment: No Problem glad it sloved your problem :)

Comment: THIS IS TRUUULY UNDERRATED

Comment: none of the above worked and i was getting kinda desperate, but this was a hidden gem!

Comment: My problem is that I was switching from an included copy of a framework to cocoa pods, but I had forgotten that the framework was still being compiled in. I removed the framework's file from the compilation step, and the error went away! Thank you so much.

Comment: It happened when I duplicate the scheme turns out it still uses the same file on the original scheme. Thanks for this

Comment: Thank you your answer was what pointed me to the real problem

Answer (score 26):

For me it was that i imported a file as a .m not a .h by mistake

Comment: That's LOL, but true ;D

Comment: this just happened to me.. I blame code completion for everyting

Answer (score 19):

Below Patch work for me..:)

```
Step 1: Go to TARGETS -> Build Settings -> No Common Blocks -> No

Step 2: Go to TARGETS -> Build Settings -> enable testability -> No
```

**Setting it back to NO solved the problem!**

Comment: Step 2: Solved my problem. Thank you :)

Comment: The enable testability was the issue for me! I did a lot of research to find that!!

Answer (score 11):

On upgrading to Xcode 8, I got a message to upgrade to recommended settings. I accepted and everything was updated.
I started getting compile time issue :

Duplicate symbol for XXXX
Duplicate symbol for XXXX
Duplicate symbol for XXXX

A total of 143 errors. 
Went to Target->Build settings -> No Common Blocks -> Set it to NO. 
This resolved the issue. The issue was that the integrated projects had code blocks in common and hence was not able to compile it. Explanation can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11233235/what-is-gcc-no-common-blocks-used-for).

Answer (score 11):

If you are moving to Xcode 7 or 8 and are opening a really old project, I've encountered this problem:

in `SomeConstFile.h`

```
NSString * const kAConstant;
```

in `SomeConstFile.m`

```
NSString *const kAConstant = @"a constant";
```

Earlier versions of the compiler assumed that the definition in the header file was extern and so including SomeConstFile.h all over the place was fine.

Now you need to explicitly declare these consts as extern:

in `SomeConstFile.h`

```
extern NSString * const kAConstant;
```

Comment: Thanks for this! Was struggling with an issue with a constants.h file I was creating lol

Comment: Thank you for the answer I too was facing the same issue and your answer worked for me...

Comment: Thanks, i was struggling for this problem for past 3-4 hrs

Answer (score 9):

This error happens when Linker is trying to link the obj files. Few reasons that i could think of for this error are:

1. The duplicated Function/Class is defined at two different places/files in the project and only one of them was supposed to compile for any variation of build command. But somehow both those files got compiled in your project. So you need to check your if-else conditions or other dependencies which adds src files to the list of files needed to be compiled and remove the un-needed file for your particular build command.
2. The duplicated Function/Class is defined accidentally at two different places/files in the project. Remove the wrong definition.
3. Clean your OBJ directory before you build again, there could be some old obj files in there from your previous builds which might be causing this conflict.

P.S i am no expert, but this is how i solved this problem when i faced it. :)

Answer (score 4):

Plz Change setting.

Step 1: Go to TARGETS -> Build Settings -> No Common Blocks -> No

Step 2: Go to TARGETS -> Build Settings -> enable testability -> No

Answer (score 3):

You face this problem when you install FireBaseAnalytics via Swift Package Manager, and Google AdMobs SDK via CocoaPods, as guided by the official documentation. You end up with duplicated libraries.

My solution to this problem is installing both FireBaseAnalytics and Google AdMobs SDK via CocoaPods.

Answer (score 2):

Well, 
some times when using SDK like FB or Libraries like Vuforia or GoogleAnalytics , adding sample projects may cause the problem that they're already including Frameworks and like so ,so you must make sure not repeating symbols you add manually while they're already included in samples

Answer (score 2):

For me, the issue was the style of creation of const, that worked fine until this iOS8.. i had a few lines as:

```
int const kView_LayoutCount = 3;
```

in my .h file. Six lines like resulted in 636 linker files once common blocks was set to NO. (14k+ if YES). Moved the lines to .m after stripping .h of the value declaration and compilation was good to go.

Hope this helps others!

Answer (score 2):

In my case reason was too stupid :

I had a Constant.h file where I had macros defined. 
I thought of doing NSString there. and did this :

```
NSString const *kGreenColor = @"#00C34E";
```

this caused the problem of Duplicate Symbols for Architecture arm64
 and Linker command failed with exit code 1. **Removing const NSString line worked for me.**

Answer (score 2):

check your include file, I had this issue because I accidentally #imported "filename.m" instead of "filename.h", autocorrect (tab) put an "m" not "h".

Comment: Thank you so much, I didn't realise I had made this mistake, was taking up all my time. Thanks again 

Answer (score 2):

The problem for me was I had manually included a framework but then also included that same framework in CocoaPods not knowing I did so. Once I removed one or the other, the problem went away

Answer (score 2):

If someone is experimenting this working on Flutter, don't try to pod deintegrate, pod init.

How I solved is running flutter clean, flutter run -d [iOS Device]

Hope can help somebody.

Answer (score 1):

From the errors, it would appear any Classes appear multiple time.Find and removed that Classes it will working.

Am creating AppDelegate.h and .m file creating multiple time. So this error will occur.Finally find and removed that classes it's working fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

to solve this problem go to Build phases and search about duplicate file 
like (facebookSDK , unityads ) and delete (extension file.o) then build again .

Answer (score 1):

See [Duplicate symbol error when adding NSManagedObject subclass, duplicate link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40460307/duplicate-symbol-error-when-adding-nsmanagedobject-subclass-duplicate-link)

Answer (score 1):

## Code

- `CrifanLibiOS.h`

```c
const int OPEN_OK = 0;
```

- `CrifanLibiOS.m`

```c
#import "CrifanLibiOS.h"
...
// use the const int value
  if (OPEN_OK == openResult){
```

and:

- include by other ObjC file

  - `openFileViewController.m`

```c
#import "CrifanLibiOS.h"
```

## Error

`ld: 6 duplicate symbols for architecture arm64`

## Reason

`CrifanLibiOS.h` be imported multiple time, and `const int` is redefined multiple time

## Solution

for ObjC, `const` variable should change to:

- **implementation** in `xxx.m`

  - `CrifanLibiOS.m`

```c
#import "CrifanLibiOS.h"

const int OPEN_OK = 0;

...
// use the const int value
  if (OPEN_OK == openResult){
```

- **declaration** in `xxx.h`, MUST with **extern**

  - `CrifanLibiOS.h`

```c
extern const int OPEN_OK;
```

Answer (score 1):

I was doing my tutorial, then I divided answers into different files, didn't mean to relate them to make a big program.

I didn't solve the problem until I **commented out the remaining lines of the "main.cpp" file** to **make sure the program can run separately** without the influence of it.

I'm not really sure about the principle of it, but I think it **might be caused by a conflict of in fact multiple "main.cpp" files.**

Just a little discovery from a first-year student, hope can help somebody.

Answer (score 1):

As none of the provided answers solved the problem for me, I want to share this workaround:

- Go to `Targets` -> {`Your-App-Target`} -> `Build Settings` -> `Other Linker Flags`
- Replace `-Objc` with `-ld64` or just add `-ld64` if not existent
- Run `Clean Build Folder` and build app again

Sources:

- https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/736590
- https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode-release-notes/xcode-15-release-notes#Linking

Answer (score 0):

For me, I created a method called `sampleMethod` in ViewController_A and created the same method in ViewController_B too, It caused me this error, then i changed the method name in ViewController_B to `secondSampleMethod`. It fixed the error.

Seems like a Good feature to reduce the code and not to duplicate the same code in many places.

I tried changing the No Common blocks from Yes to No then enabling testability from Yes to No. It didn't worked. I Checked duplicate files also in build phases, but there is no duplicate files.

Answer (score 0):

I got this issue because I was lazily defining a variable in my .m outside of a method, then in another .m file I was defining another variable with the same name outside a method. This was causing a global variable name duplicate issue.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this error which said "158 duplicate symbols for architecture armv7,  158 duplicate symbols for architecture arm64" --- If this is what you are getting too, then it means you are trying to compile a file which is importing or inheriting a framework or static library having references to C++ code or files. An easy way to handle this would be to change the extension of your .m file to .mm. This is how it gets handled if you are using Objective C, not sure on Swift though.

Also in your build settings - you can update the "other linker flags" to -lc++

Answer (score 0):

I got this issue when I had two files that had the same name on accident (large project, oops!)

Ironically they were actually the same file, I just had forgotten that I had already created one as a placeholder weeks earlier and gave it the same name again, haha!

Answer (score 0):

Sometime It works with cache cleaning in Xcode using command+shift+k

Mine issue was that I have multiple files with same name, So I removed duplicate files, In console You can see file name
Hope can help somebody.

Answer (score 0):

I had this on a Flutter project after changing dependency versions. I had to do the following:

```
pod deintegrate
flutter clean
pod install
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, it's because of the global variables.
There is a class which has a global variable like:

```
CGFloat cellHeight = 65;
```

And I build a new class which is not connected to the first class and it get the same variable too. That's say:

```
CGFloat cellHeight = 80;
```

So because of it, the problem came.
The solution is to add a `static` to modify it, so it will just work fine.

```
static CGFloat cellHeight = 80;
```

Answer (score 0):

I also have the same problem. Later, I found that there is a problem with the files opened to the public in my own library. If I only open the. h file to the public, it will be fine.[image]

Answer (score 0):

my error in xcode 14.3 and react native 0.67.5 and using react-native-qrcode-scanner is:

*2 duplicate symbols for architecture arm64*

and the solution is:
add this: use_flipper!() to podfile.

1. `ios/Podfile`
2. add: `use_flipper!()`

Answer (score 0):

The issue for me was because I duplicated target, the .m file was also copied and both has similar content. The issue was hard to find because like other resource files, for .m file it does not show any hint of which part is duplicated.