# Unity xCode Linker error - Trying to Debug

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine, google-vr

Trying to figure out how to even start debugging this issue.  I'm using Google VR on Unity, deploying to xcode for the build to iOS devices. I"ve opened the workspace instead of the project in xcode as referenced in:
[Xcode Project vs. Xcode Workspace - Differences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21631313/xcode-project-vs-xcode-workspace-differences)

I've attempted to fix as referenced in:
[Duplicate Symbols for Architecture arm64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26303782/duplicate-symbols-for-architecture-arm64/39605771)

Still getting the same error and have no idea where to go from here.

> duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_DeviceParamsSyncHelper in:
>     /Users/OriginDevIT/Documents/ODIT_ARVR/GP_Excel/builds/ios/V1.9.11.b11/Pods/GVRSDK/Libraries/libGVRSDK.a(DeviceParamsSyncHelper.mm.o)
>       /Users/OriginDevIT/Documents/ODIT_ARVR/GP_Excel/builds/ios/V1.9.11.b11/Libraries/Plugins/iOS/libgvrunity.a(DeviceParamsSyncHelper.mm.o)
>   duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_DeviceParamsSyncHelper in:
>       /Users/OriginDevIT/Documents/ODIT_ARVR/GP_Excel/builds/ios/V1.9.11.b11/Pods/GVRSDK/Libraries/libGVRSDK.a(DeviceParamsSyncHelper.mm.o)
>       /Users/OriginDevIT/Documents/ODIT_ARVR/GP_Excel/builds/ios/V1.9.11.b11/Libraries/Plugins/iOS/libgvrunity.a(DeviceParamsSyncHelper.mm.o)
>   ld: 2087 duplicate symbols for architecture arm64
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: This is sometimes caused by the same file being included twice in the Xcode project. To see if this is the case, open your project, select the project, select the 'Build Phases' tab in the project settings, and check for duplicates in the 'Compile sources' phase. Use the 'filter' box to make this easier. Also, clean the project, and clean the Xcode derived data folder, and restart Xcode

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.  Ok, I did find a duplicate in the Compile sources, and removed it. Then cleaned the project, cleaned the xCode Derived Data folder (had to search to find how to do this, but easy enough). Then restarted xCode, and on build... same error. Any idea where else I should look or anything else I can do to try to debug this.  I'm not an xCode expert and would love to avoid it completely, but sadly I'm required to use it to deploy Unity apps to iOS devices.