# Build failing on ios generic device but Ok for simulator

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have downloaded an app template from codecanyon.

When I am running on a simulator, it's running good.
But when I am trying to build on a real device or iOS generic device, it's failing with the following error:

```
> duplicate symbol l123 in:
>         /Users/sagar/Downloads/123/FoodDelivery/FoodDelivery/Resources/Frameworks/Bolts.framework/Bolts(BFAppLinkReturnToRefererView.o)
>         /Users/sagar/Downloads/123/FoodDelivery/FoodDelivery/Resources/Frameworks/Bolts.framework/Bolts(BFTask.o)
>     duplicate symbol l028 in:
>         /Users/sagar/Downloads/123/FoodDelivery/FoodDelivery/Resources/Frameworks/Bolts.framework/Bolts(BFTaskCompletionSource.o)
>         /Users/sagar/Downloads/123/FoodDelivery/FoodDelivery/Resources/Frameworks/Bolts.framework/Bolts(BFMeasurementEvent.o)
>     duplicate symbol l029 in:
>         /Users/sagar/Downloads/123/FoodDelivery/FoodDelivery/Resources/Frameworks/Bolts.framework/Bolts(BFTaskCompletionSource.o)
>         /Users/sagar/Downloads/123/FoodDelivery/FoodDelivery/Resources/Frameworks/Bolts.framework/Bolts(BFExecutor.o)
>     duplicate symbol l152 in:
>         /Users/sagar/Downloads/123/FoodDelivery/FoodDelivery/Resources/Frameworks/Bolts.framework/Bolts(BFWebViewAppLinkResolver.o)
>         /Users/sagar/Downloads/123/FoodDelivery/FoodDelivery/Resources/Frameworks/GoogleSignIn.framework/GoogleSignIn(GIDAuthentication.o)
>     duplicate symbol l153 in:
>         /Users/sagar/Downloads/123/FoodDelivery/FoodDelivery/Resources/Frameworks/Bolts.framework/Bolts(BFWebViewAppLinkResolver.o)
>         /Users/sagar/Downloads/123/FoodDelivery/FoodDelivery/Resources/Frameworks/GoogleSignIn.framework/GoogleSignIn(GIDAuthentication.o)
>     duplicate symbol l154 in:
>         /Users/sagar/Downloads/123/FoodDelivery/FoodDelivery/Resources/Frameworks/Bolts.framework/Bolts(BFWebViewAppLinkResolver.o)
>         /Users/sagar/Downloads/123/FoodDelivery/FoodDelivery/Resources/Frameworks/GoogleSignIn.framework/GoogleSignIn(GIDAuthentication.o)
>     duplicate symbol l155 in:
>         /Users/sagar/Downloads/123/FoodDelivery/FoodDelivery/Resources/Frameworks/Bolts.framework/Bolts(BFWebViewAppLinkResolver.o)
>         /Users/sagar/Downloads/123/FoodDelivery/FoodDelivery/Resources/Frameworks/GoogleSignIn.framework/GoogleSignIn(GIDAuthentication.o)
>     .....
```

ld: 91 duplicate symbols for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I am using Xcode 10.
Any idea how to solve it?

Comment: did you tried tu clean / remove derived data folder?

Comment: I have deleted derived data folder, set No common blocks to NO and enable testability to NO. I even updated my cocoapods version and deintegrated it and installed again, updated it. Still the problem persists. I dont know what else I can do

Comment: How about using a non-beta version of Xcode, something like Xcode 9.4.1?

Comment: try locating if bolts framework is used by some other framework or not. If not, there might be some framework which might be duplicated. I had similar issue where bolts and svprogressHUD both were duplicated in project.

Comment: looks like same problem, check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26303957/3824808

Comment: Are you using provisioning profile? If yes, is that a development/distribution profile?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have the same issue with `Xcode 10 beta 5`. Try to install newest beta 6, make clean, `pod deintegrate` then `pod install` and then try to build at device. In my case error is gone.

Answer (score 3):

Remove all pod files from your project by hard cleaning then reinstall

```
 sudo gem install cocoapods-deintegrate cocoapods-clean
 pod deintegrate
 pod clean
 pod install
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug with Xcode 10 beta 5 that causes to build error on real devices, and it seems fixed in Xcode 10 beta 6, upgrade and bug should be fixed

Answer (score 0):

> From the errors, it would appear that the `GoogleSign.framework`
>   already includes the `Bolts.framework` classes. Try removing the
>   additional Bolts.framework from the project.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to make a hardClean, Go to Product, press 'Alt' and select clean build folder. Then open Terminal and run :

```
rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/
```

Open Xcode everything will be recompiled.

Other option is to remove the framework and adding it again as its possible there is duplicated references to it or something like that.