# Google Cast 2.6.0 errors when building iOS project

Tags: ios, casting, google-cast

Any of you guys had errors when building your iOS project after updating to the new Google Cast 2.6.0 framework?

I get the following error:
*Default initialisation of an object of const type ‘const NSInteger’ (aka ‘const int’).*
at the following lines in class GCKDevice:

```
/** Device capability flag for video out. */
GCK_EXPORT const NSInteger kGCKDeviceCapabilityVideoOut;
/** Device capability flag for video in. */
GCK_EXPORT const NSInteger kGCKDeviceCapabilityVideoIn;
/** Device capability flag for audio out. */
GCK_EXPORT const NSInteger kGCKDeviceCapabilityAudioOut;
/** Device capability flag for audio in. */
GCK_EXPORT const NSInteger kGCKDeviceCapabilityAudioIn;
```

Comment: Have you noticed any other errors? I'm assuming you didn't see this before the update, correct?

Comment: Same problem here. Cannot build the new 2.6.0

Comment: @not_a_bot The errors only appeared after integrating Google Cast 2.6.0, no issues before.

Comment: Quick questions: 1) how are you integrating? Is it via cocoapods or linking the framework directly? 2) What version of Xcode are you using, and which  base SDK are you using?

Comment: Also: are you using this from any objective-c++ code? Wondering if that is causing different build requirements.

Comment: Checked it, definitely a objc++ thing.

Comment: Yes, one of my classes indeed is Objective-C++ and uses Chromecast.

Comment: This issue should be fixed in the recent SDK release.

Answer (score 1):

There is a bug in this version of the SDK for files compiled under Objective-C++. If you import the classes from a .mm file, there is a missing extern which will trigger a problem. As a workaround, if you can move you code to a regular .m file you should be OK (and you should be able to call out to that as long as you don't expose the GCK headers to the mm).

Comment: For the future release of the SDK do you think this will be fixed?

Comment: Yep, definitely. There is a fix in the works, and it should be in the next SDK update.

Answer (score 0):

For me it helped to switch the "No Common Blocks" compiler setting to NO:

[image]

It pretty much seems to make sense, this setting defines how duplicate variable definitions are handled by the compiler. It is explained here: [What is GCC_NO_COMMON_BLOCKS used for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11233235/what-is-gcc-no-common-blocks-used-for)

Comment: It seems that I already had this flag set to NO, the errors persist :(